# Detect missing date in string using dateutil in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a string which contains a timestamp. This timestamp may or may not contain the date it was recorded. If it does not I need to retrieve it from another source. For example:

if the string is

```
str='11:42:27.619' #It does not contain a date, just the time
```

when I use `dateutil.parser.parse(str)`, it will return me a datetime object with today's date. How can I detect when there is no date? So I can get it from somewhere else?

I can not just test if it is today's date because the timestamp may be from today and I should use the date provided in the timestamp if it exists.

Thank you

Comment: can you also share the format if date exists in str

Comment: Can't you just check the `len()` of the string?

Comment: @JayParikh It could be in a few different formats such as "2017-05-08T09:38:41.176-04:00" or "2017-05-08.09:38:41.176643", etc

Comment: @Kevin Hmmm. That might work

Comment: @ChloeeRobertson that's what i was about to say, just check length of the string.

Comment: @JayParikh I will give that a go. Thanks! :)

Comment: checking just the len() may not work if only the date is given, i.e. 12/03/96, what should be done in that case?

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is first check the string's length, if it contains it should be larger, then I would proceed as you mention.